# AngularJS: Auto-update the total price

Tags: angularjs

The html code:

```
<input placeholder='Total price' type="text" value="{{ totalPrice || '' }}" </input>
```

Angular code:

```
$scope.totalPrice = function() {
        var total = 0;
            if (itemsToBuy.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.itemsToBuy.length; i++) {
                    total += $scope.itemsToBuy[i].price;
                }
            }
        return total;
    };
```

This recursion gives a right value, but I'm having problem with displaying it.

**I want the totalPrice value to be displayed** on the screen, in the input and auto-update it's value, when the `itemsToBuy` array changes it's length.

So once again, the `total` variable holds a correct value, but it is not displayed in the input.

Thanks for any further answers.

**Edit:** For Euphoria:

> When I'm using your solution, with the 
>   `$watch` method it ends up with an error: `totalPrice is not a function`.
>   https://jsfiddle.net/scgsc7or/15/
>
> And when I'm using your first solution, with:

`<button ng-change="updateTotalPrice">ButonText</button>`

> It doesn't work either, the error displays: `[$compile:ctreq]`. https://jsfiddle.net/scgsc7or/16/

[image]

Comment: on line 3 you're not checking $scope.itemsToBuy you're checking just itemsToBuy, is that a previously declared variable or a typing error? How does your $scope.totalPrice method know when to execute? Does the code/functionality that changes your $scope.itemsToBuy call it?

Comment: you're missing a closing bracket in your html

Comment: @Euphoria I'm sorry. It's just a typo. Unfortunately my totalprice method doesn't know when to execute. Do you have any hints where to drop it? And how?

Comment: @Ronnie Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well K Scandrett deals with your initial question and $scope.totalPrice can't be a function.

For your second question in the comments what you need to do is add ng-change to the control you press to change itemsToBuy.

So you could define a function to update the totalPrice as follows:

```
$scope.updateTotalPrice = function(){
    $scope.totalPrice = 0;

if (itemsToBuy.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.itemsToBuy.length; i++) {
        $scope.totalPrice += $scope.itemsToBuy[i].price;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you have two options to execute that function **on demand**

1. If you are updating the itemsToBuy ie. the length is changing when you click a button then you can use ng-change on THAT button to execute your function.

```html
<button ng-change="updateTotalPrice">ButonText</button>
```

**or**

2. Use $scopes **watch** on the length of your itemsToBuy variable.

   ```
   $scope.$watch(**'itemsToBuy.length'**, function() {
       $scope.updateTotalPrice();
   });
   ```

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/scgsc7or/18/

Comment: Am I able to use this `$watch` without this first part of your answer? This first gray box?

Comment: @Patrickkx - the watch's callback is calling the first part of my answer. The function that updates the $scope.totalPrice variable. So you need that as a minimum regardless of what option you choose.

Comment: I tried it, it returns some strange values in the price input. I've made a jsfiddle especially for you, check it if you can. This is the last working version, without your solution. https://jsfiddle.net/scgsc7or/2/

Comment: You were right. That function is being executed too many times. I have to do something with it.

Comment: @Patrickkx - Alright I've updated the fiddle and the answer. Please observe how the function of getting the totalPrice is not on the scope but only called from within the $watch on the itemsToBuy.length. So it triggers ONLY when the itemsToBuy.length changes. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I will review your code right now, just wanna let u know that Ive uploaded a gif. It acts very strange, it executes too many times. I hope your solution will help me fix it. Going to see it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126413/discussion-between-euphoria-and-patrickkx).

Answer (score 1):

TotalPrice is a function, so you can't use it like `{{totalPrice}}`.  That would only be true if totalPrice was a variable.

What you need is something like

```
$scope.totalPrice = 0;

if (itemsToBuy.length > 0) {
   for (var i = 0; i < $scope.itemsToBuy.length; i++) {
      $scope.totalPrice += $scope.itemsToBuy[i].price;
   }
}
```

Which you would call whenever itemsToBuy changes

Comment: Okey but how to tell angular to change the totaPrice value whenever itemsToBuy.length changes? And wouldn't it be better if I put this if statement into some function?

Answer (score 1):

As K Scandrett pointed out, totalPrice is a function, so you need to execute it to display its return value. So `{{totalPrice || ''}}` should be `{{totalPrice()}}`.

Comment: This works because he is returning the function which will now execute on a digest of the page. However that means this will execute multiple times throughout the lifecycle of the page. So this will not JUST execute when required because the $scope.itemsToBuy had changed.

Comment: @Euphoria Is it bad solution? I marked it as the best answer because it works. Should I delete this solution? And choose another one?

Comment: This works but not how or why you want it to. You want the totalPrice to update only WHEN the itemsToBuy are changed. So this working because when you change your itemsToBuy because it is on the $scope object it triggers a "digest" to occur on the page then angularjs executes this function to run the {{totalPrice()}} and update the value. This however means it will execute on every OTHER digest also, many times. Even when you aren't updating your itemsToBuy.

Comment: @Euphoria Do you have any better idea, to avoid multiply use of this function? But only when the length changes?

Comment: @Patrickkx - I have updated my answer to avoid multiple usage and offered 2 options.